# SQLite3, Combine multiple rows in one

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have two tables cities (as C) and routes (as R)

C:

```
 ____ ______
| id | city |
|____|______|
| 1  |  A   |
| 2  |  B   |
|____|______|
```

R:

```
 ____ ______ ____ __________
| id | from | to | distance |
|____|______|____|__________|
| 1  |  1   | 2  | 100      |
| 2  |  2   | 1  | 100      |
|____|______|____|__________|
```

(my expectation): I want to combine and join my tables to the following form:

```
 ____ ______ ____________ ____ __________ __________
| id | from | fromAsText | to | toAsText | distance |
|____|______|____________|____|__________|__________|
| 1  | 1    | A          | 2  | B        | 100      |
| 2  | 2    | B          | 1  | A        | 100      | 
|____|______|____________|____|__________|__________|
```

To add one value isn't a problem

```
    SELECT
    r.*
    s.city as fromAsText
    FROM
    routes as r,
    cities as s
    WHERE
    r.from = s.id
```

But I haven't any Ideas how to achieve my goals! Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your expectation results correctly?

Comment: Please don't use comma-separated joins. There were made redundant in standard SQL 1992! Use explicit joins instead: `FROM routes as r INNER JOIN cities as c ON  c.id = r.from`.

Comment: Argh, There was an error,  The expectation was updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply join the city table twice:

```
select r.id, r.from, c_from.city as from_city, r.to, c_to.city as to_city, r.distance
from routes r
join cities c_from on c_from.id = r.from
join cities c_to on c_to.id = r.to
order by r.id;
```